# A hyperelliptic curve of genus $g$ can be embedded into Hirzebruch surface $F_{g+1}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-curves

In the paper "On the Moduli of Curves on Rational Ruled Surface" by A. Fauntleroy, during the proof of theorem 4.2, the author states the result that a hyperelliptic curve of genus $g$ sits on Hirzebruch surface $F_{g+1}$. For the proof, he cites section 6.2 of "Weighted Projective Varieties" by I. Dolgachev. However I could not find the proof there (the article that I found has only 4 sections), so I assume it was miscited.

So I wanted to ask how one can prove the statement. Alternatively, an appropriate reference should suffice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C$ be a hyperelliptic curve of genus $g$ with the hyperelliptic covering $\pi \colon C \to \mathbb{P}^1$. Its branch divisor has degree $2g + 2$, hence
$$
\pi_*\mathcal{O}_C \cong \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-g-1).
$$
By adjunction, there is a surjective morphism
$$
\pi^*(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-g-1)) \to \mathcal{O}_C.
$$
By the universal property of the projective bundle this gives the embedding
$$
C \to \mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1} \oplus \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-g-1)) = F_{g+1}.
$$